# Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword not firing .then() until after UI focus changes

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, redux-thunk

I'm using firebase `.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then()` for authentication in a react-native Android project.

I have the function called on an onPress button event. The authentication does take place but for some reason, the `.then()` does not fire unless I tap somewhere else on the screen. It will happily wait 5 mins until I tap somewhere other than the button to fire.

I can see that the auth is taking place. It's just the `.then()` promise that hangs until focus is shifted away from the button.

I'm using react-native 0.59.5 and firebase 5.1.0 node libraries. I've tried console.logging each step and it's clear the `then()` is where it fails. Strangely `catch()` works immediately.

```
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER })

    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
      .catch(() => {
        firebase
          .auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
          .catch(loginUserFail(dispatch))
      })
  }
}

const loginUserFail = dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_FAIL })
}

const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch, user) => {
  console.log('Firing success')
  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    payload: user
  })
}
```

In the above example, loginUserFail will run immediately if auth fails but loginUserSuccess will wait indefinitely until I tap somewhere else in the application.

Comment: I have same issue, did you able to find a solution ?

Comment: Any news on this subject, i refuse to accept that I cannot debug while using this promise-pattern.

Comment: I have same issue with @angular/fire's library. longUserFail executes immediately but success will wait indefinitely.

Answer (score 7):

Do you have your remote debugger open in a Chrome browsers?
Close it (debugger), reload app in simulator and it will work as expected.

Comment: Godlike solution for modern development! Thank you, sir

Answer (score 3):

Just stop the Remote Debugger in your application, hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the "then" promisse:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .catch(error => {
                dispatch(loginUserFail(error));
            });
```

After that try to create an action with this comand:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                console.log('success sign in');
                dispatch(loginUserSuccess(user));
            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
            }
        });
```